# Predictive Black Screen issue with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, 18.04, amd-graphics

**Device Details: Acer Aspire Timeline X 3820TG**

- Processor: Intel Core i3 CPU M 380 @2.53GHz
- Graphics: Intel Ironlake    Mobile
- GNOME: 3.28.1
- OS Architecture: 64-bit
- Installation: **Ubuntu 18.04**

NOTE: Graphics from ATI HD5470 isn't detected by the system.

**Issue**
Whenever I try to open "Settings" or any other native application of the OS, the screen goes black for few minutes and resumes back opening the desired application.

**Fixes Tried**

1. Updated `/etc/default/grub` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
   to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"`

**Result:** The system uses LLVMPipe as default graphics driver. The predictive blacking out is gone, but there is only a default option to set resolution to 1024x768, which is ugly.

2. Added graphics-drivers ppa from olbaf `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`, performed an update and installed graphics drivers.

**Result:** No fixation.

3. Tried looking for Proprietary driver for ATI at the "Additional Drivers" section.

**Result:** Didn't find any driver listed.

Is there anything that can solve this "predictive" black screen issue on my machine?